# need help on SQL condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Assume i have two tables lpn and lpn_detail 
If we use lpn_id in lpn table we will get only one record.
If we use lpn_id in lpn_detail table we will get multiple records or we may get only one record.

when we joined these two tables, I need a condition where mutiple records of Lpn_Detail should only fetch as a result.

```
select * from lpn inner join LPN_DETAIL
on lpn.lpn_id = lpn_detail.lpn_id
where 1=1
and lpn.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' 
and lpn.INBOUND_OUTBOUND_INDICATOR='I';
```

Comment: can you show us what these two tables looks like and what's the output that you're expecting from those data?

Comment: select * from lpn 
where LPN_ID='7540023';

Comment: SELECT * FROM LPN_DETAIL
WHERE LPN_ID='7540023';

Comment: from the first table (lpn) its a primary key i will get only one records
if i use in Lpn_detail i will any records around 4-5 records in general
when we join both the table i need a condition where the lpn_detail  having mutiple records should fetch.

Comment: okay, that's a start. so what will be the output?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is ok.
If you want to select only specific columns then use column name instead of * in your select query.

```
select col1,col2,col3 from lpn inner join LPN_DETAIL
on lpn.lpn_id = lpn_detail.lpn_id
where 1=1
and lpn.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' 
and lpn.INBOUND_OUTBOUND_INDICATOR='I';
```

Answer (score 0):

your query is ok and you must write LPN_DETAIL.* instead of * to only fetch LPN_DETAIL columns. you can write it as:

```
select LPN_DETAIL.* from lpn inner join LPN_DETAIL
on lpn.lpn_id = lpn_detail.lpn_id
where 1=1
and lpn.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' 
and lpn.INBOUND_OUTBOUND_INDICATOR='I';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only records with multiple LPN_DETAIL for same LPN you may use either subquery:

```
select * from lpn inner join LPN_DETAIL
on lpn.lpn_id = lpn_detail.lpn_id
where 1=1
and lpn.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' 
and lpn.INBOUND_OUTBOUND_INDICATOR='I'
and lpn_detail.lpn_id in (select lpn_id 
                            from lpn_detail 
                           group by lpn_id 
                          having count(*)>1);
```

or analytic function:

```
select * from(
select lpn.*,lpn_detail.*,
       count(*) OVER (partition by lpn_detail.lpn_id) cnt
from lpn inner join LPN_DETAIL
on lpn.lpn_id = lpn_detail.lpn_id
where 1=1
and lpn.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' 
and lpn.INBOUND_OUTBOUND_INDICATOR='I')
where cnt>1;
```

Comment: Your query fetched multiple records from lpn_detail but it also fetched the only one record.I need only mutiple records not single records.Is that possible?





select * from lpn inner join LPN_DETAIL
on lpn.lpn_id = lpn_detail.lpn_id
where 1=1
and lpn.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' 
and lpn.INBOUND_OUTBOUND_INDICATOR='I'
and lpn_detail.lpn_id in (select lpn_id 
                            from lpn_detail 
                           group by lpn_id 
                          having count(*)>1);